# how to change the icon of leaf node in dojo tree?

Tags: dojo, tree

I have created a tree containing information about server and its VMs.
I want to change the icon of VM to green if the VM is power on or to red if the VM is poweroff.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to switch the tree node css class depending on if the VM is on or off.

```
ar iconFunc = dojo.hitch(this, function (item, opened) { 
                if(item !== undefined && item !== null) {
                    if (item.VmOn!== undefined) {
                        return "VmOn";
                    }
                    else {
                        return "VmOff";
                    }
                }
            });
```

When creating your tree, pass the iconFunc in the constructor params:

```
var treeParams = {
    getIconClass : iconFunc, //attach the custom icon function
...};
var myTree = new dijit.Tree(treeParams);
```

Then create css styles called VmOn and VmOff:

```
.VmOn {
    background: url(path to your image for VmOn) no-repeat;
```

The store items that make up the tree nodes will need a property of VmOn or VmOff or change the iconFunc to examine the store items in a different way...

Answer (score 3):

This might be another way of doing the same thing,

```
getIconStyle:function(item, opened){
    if(!item.root){
        if(!item.children){
            // Style the nodes that not have childrens
            return {backgroundColor: "red"};
        }else{
            // Style the nodes that have childrens
            return {backgroundColor: "blue"};
        }
    }else{
        // Style the root node here
        return {backgroundColor: "orange"};
    }
}
```

you can also use getIconClass to return appropriate css class name.